# TextViews to be slide out when when activity change

Tags: android, android-animation

I have many activities with each having a group of textViews. what i want to

1) when activity loaded all the textViews should slide in.

2) when second activity loads the textViews of first activity slides out.

However, I already figured out the transition/animation, and also achieved the solution for first by calling the animation in onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus).
but I am unable to find the correct method through which I have to called slide out part.

this is my slide_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

this is my slide_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Here I call slide in and slide out but slide out is not working.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        animShow();

    }  
    else
    {
        animHide();
    }
}
```

this is my animHide method

```
private void animHide()
{
    etname.startAnimation(animHide[0]);     
    etmail.startAnimation(animHide[1]);             
    etmobile.startAnimation(animHide[2]);       
    etaddress.startAnimation(animHide[3]);      
    etlanguage.startAnimation(animHide[4]);     
}
```

Comment: Please provide the functions you've mentioned animHide, animShow. Also you would need to set the setFillAfter property to be true

Comment: @humblerookie It is still not working after setFillAfter property.

Answer (score 0):

When starting the second `Activity` from you first one, call [`overridePendingTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) immediately after you call `startActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest watching [Custom Activity Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA&index=63&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0) from Google's DevBytes series.

An expert from Google, Chet Haase, explains in details how to deal Activity transition animations. Below the video you will also find link to the source code of  the presented example.

If you are interested in more Android animations, checkout the rest of DevBytes series episodes.